# Как сделать превью слайдера с правой стороны?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper

Хочу получить такой результат, но не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня такой слайдер:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }

      body {
        background: #000;
        color: #000;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }

      .mySwiper2 {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .mySwiper {
        height: 20%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      .mySwiper .swiper-slide {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.4;
      }

      .mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Swiper -->

    <div
      style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff"
      class="swiper mySwiper2"
    >
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
    <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 4,
        freeMode: true,
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
      });
      var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        thumbs: {
          swiper: swiper,
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: не надо писать код ссылкой

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper1", {
  direction: "vertical",
  //loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});

const swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
  //loop: true,
  watchOverflow: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
  direction: "vertical",
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}

.swiper-container {
  display: flex;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.mySwiper2 {
  width: 75%;
}

.mySwiper1 .swiper-button-prev,
.mySwiper1 .swiper-button-next {
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  right: auto;
}

.mySwiper1 .swiper-button-prev {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;  
}

.mySwiper1 .swiper-button-next {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;  
}



.mySwiper1 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.mySwiper1 .swiper-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  max-height: 25%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.mySwiper1 .swiper-slide-active,
.mySwiper1 .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div>
  <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я безумно благодарен за отклики,однако у меня почему то стрелки не появились